# Can't center in <DIV> tag

Tags: css, html

I've tried everything on this site to get my yahoo pipe to be centered on the page without centering the text within the pipe and nothing works.  I really need a second set of eyes on this one!
Here's the code I have:

The CSS:

```
#pipe_container{
    width: 850px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#event_pipe {  
    position: relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:100%px;  
    height:350px;  
    background-color:#888;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
 <div id="pipe_container">
   <div id="event_pipe">     
       <script src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/pps/listbadge_1.6.js">
        { 
          "pipe_id":"2a44070dcf6974aea04ad155a76caef4",
          "_btype":"list",
          "width":"80%",
          "height":"350px"
        }
      </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can't use the centering attributes in the "event_pipe" code because it centers everything, including the text.  I want the text to remain to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work using CSS. I had to pass it in as an argument to the pipe:

```
 <div id="pipe_container">
   <div id="event_pipe">     
       <script src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/pps/listbadge_1.6.js">
        {
          "pipe_id":"2a44070dcf6974aea04ad155a76caef4",
          "_btype":"list",
          "width":"80%",
          "height":"350px",
          "margin":"auto"
        }
      </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Notice the last 2 lines of the JSON:

```
"height":"350px",
"margin":"auto"
```

That's what did the trick.

[Here's a link to the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhdwk/).

Answer (score 0):

Try  changing the #event_pipe rule to:

```
#event_pipe > div {  
    position: relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:100%px;  
    height:350px;  
    background-color:#888;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

add your style:

```
#event_pipe div:first-child {
          margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your head section for local testing to prevent it from going into quirks mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and Try this css

```
#pipe_container{
  width: 850px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
 }
#event_pipe > div{
  margin:0 auto;
 }
#event_pipe {  
position: relative;
text-align:left; 
height:350px;  
background-color:#888;
padding:0px;
margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Davan, I tried this too and still not centered.  It's like something is overriding the code, but the background attribute works...  I'm baffled...

Comment: That is rather strange because I tested that CSS in IE 7,8,9 Chrome and FireFox.  There could be an issue when you are testing it locally in IE that it will push you into quirks mode.  Put this as the first meta in the head section of your HTML and try it.<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  another thing to try is click F12 to go into developer tools and make sure that document mode is not in quirks.